# Human toes rigged not deforming correctly

Tags: rigging, bones

I rigged up a human foot, using only one bone to control all the toes. When I rotate the bone up or down the toes don't all stay at the same level.

[image]

I want them to stay flat, at the same level, like how they are when the bone is not bent up or down.

[image]

As you can see, the toes are all weighted the same, yet the are not level when rotated up or down.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your weights? Select the mesh, press Ctrl + Tab, then select the bone. The weight assigned to these toe bones should be shown.

Comment: @Leander I edited the post for you.

Comment: @BlenderGuest could there be some other bone's influence only on the Toe, and not on other fingers, thus making the Toe less influenced by the bone you're posing? the above picture is in perspective mode, though, and not aligned, from the side the difference could be less evident... you could rig single fingers, to get better individual control, too.

Comment: To check if there more multiply influences as m.ardito suggested, select a vertice of the big toe and check the "Vertex Weights"  section in the Properties panel in the 3D view. https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=328682&d=1408770170
Consider uploading your file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

The easyest way to do what you described is probebly to rig each of the tose seprat and fix them separat.

If you rig the tose as one bone they will be deformed as one object and will probebly create a new problem if you fix one.
The deformation is done lineal and you whold need to make a exponetial deformation to make it work. You could cheat and play with the weights and make it god enoth but it will be limeted.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because our toes don't have their origin point in the middle of the foot, they each have their own so if you want them to be more precise but still have just one bone to control then you would need to have one bone for each toe and then have them copy the rotations of this bone you already have to use as a controller. This way each toe has their own origin but you still just worry about moving one bone.

If what you're looking for is optimization then what you could do is add more weight to the smaller toes for the foot bone so that they're not so heavily controlled by the toe bone, they'll still follow it but a little bit less and it'll look better although not as good as if you had a bone for each toe. But that's how optimization works, you have to sacrifice small details.